# php. dictionary data structure, (integer, string) as a key

Tags: php

In python dictionary can use tuples as keys. So I can use as a key next combination: `(integer, string)`. I want to do the same in PHP. Standard [PHP array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) can use only strings OR integers. [SplObjectStorage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php) uses only objects as a key.

How can get the same functionality in PHP?

Comment: You could store the integer keys as a string, like `array('123' => 'foo');`, although why you want to mix numeric and string keys is unclear.

Comment: JamWaffles, tuples are actually a pretty common structure found in many languages.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is that you cannot. Functionally equivalent though should be a simple:

```
$array["$int,$str"]
```

Or maybe a multi-dimensional array:

```
$array[$int][$str]
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't have any tuple datatype, but you can easily make a wrapper which combines an int and a string into a string-only representation:

```
function t($num, $str) { // t for tuple
  return $num . ', ' . $str;
}

$array[t(15, "hello")] = $random_data;
```